# Is a geo_distance query with linestring or multipolygon geo type possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have not been able to find any examples of this, but I have multipolygon shapes (and will be operating on linestrings once I figure this out) stored in ES and need to find the closest point of the multipolygon (or linestring) from a given point.

Is this even possible ES?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

at the moment ES just supports the basic operations on shapes. This means if shapes are *disjoint*, *intersect* or if one lies *within* another. Distances between geo_shapes could not be calculated so far. To be able to solve you problem, you need to index the shapes control points separately as geo_points and filter these by distance.
I think in the near future ES will at least support calculation of distances between shapes.

Cheers,
Florian